# Webdriver IO run all commands sequentially

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, promise, webdriver

I cannot understand how to correctly handle execution flow in `Webdriver.io`.

Here is my function

```
checkOrderStatus(info, callback) {
    let browserClient = this._webDriverClient;
    // Make order flow
    browserClient.init()
        .url("http://localhost")
        .selectByVisibleText("products", "MacBook")
        .setValue("input[name='first_name']", info.name)
        .setValue("input[name='address']", info.address)
        .click("button[name='confirm']");
    let errorElements = browserClient.element('.error');
    if (errorElements.length > 0) {
        callback.onError("Error");
    }
    else {
        let successElements = browserClient.element(".success");
        if (successElements.length > 0) {
            callback.onSuccess("Success");
        }
    }
    browserClient.end();
}
```

However `browserClient.element` returns `status : pending`. I need something like promises chain that a whole chain won't finish until all then statements are executed if there were no exception.

The provided example is really simple, there could be more actions even after finding elements.

Could someone suggest how to handle this chain sequentially like a promise chain.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below. You can use browser.waitUnit to hold the contorl within browser.waitUnit block to complete the action. If action is not complete it will throw time out!

```
browser.url("http://localhost");

browser.waitUntil(function () { 
    browser.isVisible(requiredelement).then(function(isVisible){
    if(isVisible){
        browser.selectByVisibleText("products", "MacBook")
                .then(function() {
                        browser.setValue("input[name='first_name']", info.name)
                        browser.setValue("input[name='address']", info.address)
                }).then(function(){
                        browser.click("button[name='confirm']");
        });
    }
  });
}, 5000, 'time out ! element is not visible..');
```